# No "Extract Here" right click menu on .001 (rar? 7z?) file?

Tags: extract

Using nemo 5.2.4
not sure what file it is, but it can be opened on file-roller, just there's too many `.001` files in separate directory to extract one by one `unrar x bla.001`.

Answer (score 2):

Files with numeric extension may be part of muilt-volume archives (e.g. rar split archives).

If that is the case here you need to locate all the separate files and place them in a single folder together with e.g. the *.rar (=archive) file that has the same name; then access the archive file only.

The archive utility will behave as if there was just a single large file.

*Note:
file.001 is generally the SECOND file in a set of "split-archive" files, there may be up to a total of 999 such files in a set.

file.rar, file.zip, ..., is normally the first; the file to launch extraction and all that on, **the first** of possibly one thousand files.*